# Python does not convert date

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have this code

```
X_train= df[df["Date"]<datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)].drop(Target, axis=1)
y_train= df[df["Date"]<datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)][Target]
```

but I got this error

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'

my Date field looks like this "2019-08-07", "2018-11-26"

therefore, I changed the type from str to date using

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

then called my orgonal code

```
X_train= df[df["Date"]<datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)].drop(Target, axis=1)
y_train= df[df["Date"]<datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)][Target]
```

but still getting same error

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'

how to fix that?

Comment: The index is df["Date"]< (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)) right?

Comment: this is the filter condition

Comment: I'm asking if the brackets are correct.

Comment: yes they are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

X_train= df[df["Date"]<datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=60)].drop(Target, axis=1)
y_train= df[df["Date"]<datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=60)][Target]
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 1):

You can working with datetimes with [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) for remove times with [`Timestamp.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.normalize.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.normalize()
today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
```

Or [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) with [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.floor('d')
today = pd.to_datetime('today').floor('d')
```

And then filter:

```
X_train= df[df["Date"] < today - pd.Timedelta(days=30)].drop(Target, axis=1)
y_train= df.loc[df["Date"] < today - pd.Timedelta(days=30), 'Target']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as:

```py
df["Date"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df["Date"], "%Y-%m-%d").date()

X_train= df[(datetime.date.today() - df["Date"]) > datetime.timedelta(days=30)].drop(Target, axis=1)
```

Comment: geting this error TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: Is df["Date"] a series? You need to input a single value or perform the operation from on whole column

Answer (score 0):

check the data type of column Date: `df[Date].dtype`.
If it's a series, do the following:

```
X_train= df[(datetime.date.today() - df["Date"].dt.date) > datetime.timedelta(days=30)].drop(Target, axis=1)
```

If its string convert it to datetime like you mentioned and then call the above code.